# MySQL Workbench: Assertion Failed wb->get_root().is_valid()

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I had run a query on MySQL workbench and after running for a long time MySQL Workbench crashed. Ever since, when I try to open MySQL Workbench it says gives an error saying assertion failed.[Attached is the screen shot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCPL.jpg)

Could you please help me with this.

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: Reinstall mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely is that your settings xml and/or connection xml has been corrupted. To fix this rename or remove wb_options.xml and/or connections.xml from the MySQL data folder before you start WB next time. Those files will be recreated if they don't exist, but you lose any custom settings + your set-up connections.

On Windows this folder is under `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench`.

Comment: I am not able to find the xml files. Could you please guide me through.